# Stagger Traces in a Flex Circuit?

Tags: reliability, fpc

I am designing a connector to PCB interface using a flex-circuit.  Stackup is R-F775 2-layers with plated thru-holes and stiffeners (though the area in question has only traces).  I'm wondering if it is better from a reliability standpoint for traces on either side of the board to be opposing one another or alternating?  The PCB will not see continuous flexing but will be used in a high vibration environment.  I'm not concerned with impedance issues in this application, I'm purely asking about mechanical reliability of the copper.

Opposing:
[image: Opposing:]

Alternating:
[image: Alternating]

Thanks!

Comment: There should be no abrupt change in direction and use rounded corners with a  smooth 5x radius.  I think opposing traces  are stronger when no sharp bends are made.

Comment: The mechanical stress on the traces will be slightly greater if they are directly opposite each other. However I think it will work fine either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to be alternating.

Why? this reduces the chance of I-beaming. If you refer to IPC-2223 "Sectional Design Standard for Flexible Printed Boards"

> Conductors in double-sided circuits should not be placed directly
>   over each other, which produces an ‘‘I’’ beam effect. This condition
>   may be necessary due to electrical considerations; however, mechanical
>   installation requirements must be considered (see Figure 5-5).

[image]

Also, traces on a flexi should be perpendicular to the bend so if those traces at 45deg occur at the point of bend, change the design

[image]

Comment: Does it justify why the traces should be perpendicular? Because my understanding is that they experience the most strain in that scenario.

Comment: And make sure that if you have traces that flex, that they don't have sharp turns, curves are better. If you've ever wanted to make a curved trace an FFC is a place where it's a great idea. A curved trace is only necessary at the points that might flex.